# How can I use an OVER statement in spotfire when connected to an external database?

Tags: oracle, window-functions, spotfire

1. Usually, I have been using the following calculated column when importing the data from an excel file:

   ```
   (Sum([Units]) - Sum([Units]) OVER (PreviousPeriod([Axis.Columns]))) / Sum([Units]) OVER (PreviousPeriod([Axis.Columns])) * 100 as [% Difference]
   ```
2. In this scenario, however, the data is coming directly from an Oracle database.
   When I try to create the calculated column, I get the error message:

> "Could not find function: 'PreviousPeriod' "

3. I have done some research and found that I should be using the THEN keyword, but I have the same problem when I try to insert it after the aggregated expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import that date via an `INFORMATION LINK` or `EMBED` the data in your analysis in order to use the majority of the functions in SPOTFIRE. If you must keep your data EXTERNAL, that is not connected via in Information Link or Embedded, you will not be able to use all the functions within SPOTFIRE.